# AMPscript help on If else statement

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I have a data extension that has a field called "veh_model_name". I want to create an If/then ampscript code to change the value "Lancer SportBack" to "Lancer" but return the regular field values if the values are not "Lancer SportBack".  Then I want to place the variable in the subject line of my email. Here is what I have:

```
%%[
    var @subject
    set @subject = veh_model_name
]%%
%%[IF @subject == "Lancer SportBack" THEN]%%

  Lancer

%%[ELSE]%%

  %%=v(@subject)=%%

  ENDIF
]%%
```

Comment: Is veh_model_name a field in your data extension? If so it needs to be in [square brackets].

Comment: Is always good to use `AttributeValue("veh_model_name")` and checking for `empty()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't retrieve the value correctly and also forgot to open the AMPscript-Block for your ENDIF, which will cause a validation error. So I suggest trying the following code:

```
%%[
    var @subject
    set @subject = Lookup("NAME_OF_YOUR_DATA_EXTENSION", "veh_model_name", "NAME_OF_THE_EMAIL_COLUMN", AttributeValue("emailaddr"))
]%%
%%[IF @subject == "Lancer SportBack" THEN]%%

  Lancer

%%[ELSE]%%

    %%=v(@subject)=%%

%%[ENDIF]%%
```

**The only things you need to modify are:**

- replace `NAME_OF_YOUR_DATA_EXTENSION` with the name of your data extension
- replace `NAME_OF_THE_EMAIL_COLUMN` with the name of the column containing the email address in your data extension

Comment: Hi Markus,  Thanks for responding, I entered the code above into my HTML code within <script></script> section.  also plae the Ampscript variable %%=v(@subject)=%% in the subject line "Your %%=v(@subject)=%% anniversary is almost here.".  but when I create a send preview.  I do not see any values from my DE.  This is how it looks. "Your anniversary is almost here."  I am not sure why that is?

Comment: You don't need to place AMPscript code inside a script-tag. Place the code whereever you like to output the variable. Is your data extension the entry event's data extension? This is necessary for the code above to work. Otherwise you need to look the field up in the other data extension querying it by the primary key.

Comment: Hi Markus, I am just getting my feet wet using SFMC so the jargan terminology of SFMC i do not have down pack yet.  I am assuming you mean if the DE is having data imported by a form or landing page of some sort.  If so, then no it's not an entry event data extension.  It's just mass of data records that was imported to a DE.  So I would have to do field look up.  I have two primary keys "vin" and "email adrress".  How do I look these up?  Thanks for you help.

Comment: Where are you using the amp script? In an email? If so, how is this email sent? Is it sent from journey builder? A journey has an entry event hat starts it and this event has a data extension (which is the entry event data extension).

Comment: I am using the amscript in the subject line of the email, under properties. Oh ok no I am not using journey builder. I am sending the email as a "guided send".

Answer (score -1):

A good AMPscript Language documentation is mentioned here for reference: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/languageElements.htm

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour] and read [answer]. Links alone tend not to be good answers (even if they are to the official documentation). To me, this answer feels incomplete. The OP (**O**riginal **P**oster of the question) appears to have a grasp on the basics, but was asking for help in figuring out what their syntax error was. I think the other existing answer is a good template. It covers _what_ OP's issue is, and _how_ to fix it. Including some explanation as to _why_ the fix works is also a generally good idea.